# unable to add check to restrict value if value is already present in info array

Tags: javascript

updating the value only if matches mnemonic and value should not present in info array for currentTab which is present in items data without changing original items
current code is working fine for mnemonic check but unable to add check for value(which is present in any other info array)
added check i.value !== obj.value, but its not working

```js
let items = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'newValue'}]},{tab:'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim'}]},{tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt'}]}];

let expectedOutput = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'newValue'}]},{tab:'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim'}]},{tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt'}]}];


let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = { mnemonic: 'first', value: 'newValue' };

const updateItems = (items, currentTab, obj) =>{
  return items.map(item => {
  //check if the provided tab is matching with the item.tab
    if(item.tab === currentTab) {
      return {
        ...item,
        info: item.info.map(i => ({
            ...i,
            ...(i.mnemonic === obj.mnemonic && i.value !== obj.value && { value: obj.value })
        }))
      }
    } else return {...item}
  })
} 

console.log(updateItems(items, currentTab, obj))
```

Comment: your `items` and `expectedOutput` is same

Comment: yeah, thats correct, in this scenario, it should not update, even though mnemonic matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for already existing value using `Array#some`

```js
let items = [{
  tab: 'tab1',
  info: [{
    mnemonic: 'first',
    value: 'alm'
  }, {
    mnemonic: 'second',
    value: 'newValue'
  }]
}, {
  tab: 'tab2',
  info: [{
    mnemonic: 'first',
    value: 'kim'
  }, {
    mnemonic: 'second',
    value: 'tim'
  }]
}, {
  tab: 'tab3',
  info: [{
    mnemonic: 'first',
    value: 'wint'
  }, {
    mnemonic: 'second',
    value: 'telt'
  }]
}];



let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = {
  mnemonic: 'first',
  value: 'newValue'
};

const updateItems = (items, currentTab, obj) => {
  return items.map(item => {
    //check if the provided tab is matching with the item.tab
    if (item.tab === currentTab) {
      return {
        ...item,
        info: item.info.map(i => ({
          ...i,
          value: (i.mnemonic === obj.mnemonic && i.value !== obj.value && !item.info.some(_v=>_v.value == obj.value)) ? obj.value : i.value
          
        }))
      }
    } else return { ...item
    }
  })
}

console.log(updateItems(items, currentTab, obj))
```